# good coding practice - writing multiple commands in one line of code c#

Tags: c#

I want to create a string pattern which would require me to write 2 lines of code:

```
string linePattern = "|";
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) linePattern += "{" + i + ",-" + sizes[i] + "}|";
```

would it now be considered a good or a bad practice to write that in one line to see what the string is made of easier:

```
string linePattern = "|"; for (int i=0; i<columns; i++) linePattern += "{"+i+",-"+sizes[i]+ "}|";
```

final string would be for example:

```
"|{0,-4}|{1,-2}|{2,-7}|{3,-3}|{4,-8}|";
```

EDIT:

Reason for this question is, that variable declaration and assignment in two separate lines is incredibly ugly from my point of view. Is there another way to write this string that would be considered good practice? (note that this pattern might have to be extended based on the amount of columns)

```
string linePattern = /* string generator here */;

echo("linePattern = |{0,-4}|{1,-2}|{2,-7}|{3,-3}|{4,-8}| ");
```

Comment: It's just not very readable. What purpose does having it fit in a single line serve?

Comment: Whatever reads better. In this case, I'd suggest more lines is more readable, and there's no penalty for it.

Comment: What is your end goal here? What do you want it on one line for? you could get cleverer with a string join and `Select` linq

Comment: Vote to close as opinion-based.

Comment: I am not used to reading that kind of code so for me personally, it's not a good practice. The best practice tho is to stick with the conventions you or your team established. If that's one of them go for it. :)

Comment: There's nothing bad in using multiple lines. Quite the opposite is true, if you have to scroll to the right side it's not readable at all. Stackoverflow gives a good impression because i have to scroll your single line already.

Comment: the reason why I ask this questions because lambds expressions are following a similar approach I believe. And with todays 16:9 monitors line width should not be that much of a problem nowadays. but I understand that this is a bad practice. for me its just incredibly ugly to have an "empty" variable assignment such as 'string linePattern = ""'

Comment: For this particular situation you might want to look at using [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2#Adding).
Alternatively, using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).
But as others have said, putting too much code on one line is generally regarded as "poor form".

Comment: The question reminded me of a trainee programmer I had working for me a long time ago - one module he presented had no blank lines or unnecessary white-space on the basis that he had been told good programmers write compact code. On another occasion he presented apparently uncommented code - when I complained he said he had started all comments at column 81 (good old days of 25x80 monitors) because it made his code look tidier.

Comment: @julianbechtold Lambda can be multiple line. If it makes it better to read then you should place it on more lines

Comment: No matter how large a monitor is, your eyes can't easily follow those long lines. Do have a look at a newspaper! Notice something? Look again! - Aslo: Do you really want to have to scan for a possible `;` ??

Comment: Is 5 lines an option here? I mean curly braces are not necessary but strongly Recommended. Even for a one line for, I would use curly brace. They cost Nothing. New line cost nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is bad practice. It is not only for C# but for all languages.

Many of the software companies and also frameworks and languages have coding guidelines that discourage typing more than X symbols in one line.

Also IDEs have one vertical line that displays where your line should end.

Sometimes in the modern 4K monitors this limitations seems quite conservative but remember that not everyone has such monitor. So we should stick to them.

This is done because it is not intuitive to scroll over the line, especially to read more than one think that should be logically separated.

Also in my opinion skipping the {} even if the loop contains only one command is bad practice too.